# Using react-number-format: cannot type more than one symbol at once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, uitextfield, react-number-format

I am using [react-number-format](https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format) package inside of my TextField (material-ui). It is having strange behavior and not letting me put more than one symbol at once in the TextField. When I start typing after first click the Field is not focused anymore. I have used the same thing in other projects and it is working fine but here I cannot see from where the problem is coming. Here is the sandbox:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/little-cherry-ubcjv?file=/src/App.js

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { TextField} from "@material-ui/core";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";

export default function App() {
  const [minAssets, setMinAssets] = useState();

const NumberFormatCustom = (props) => {
    const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;
    return (
      <NumberFormat
        {...other}
        getInputRef={inputRef}
        onValueChange={(values) => {
          onChange({
            target: {
              name: props.name,
              value: values.value,
            },
          });
        }}
        thousandSeparator
        isNumericString
        prefix="$"
      />
    );
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <TextField
          label="Min Assets"
          value={minAssets}
          onChange={(e) => setMinAssets(e.target.value)}
          name="minAssets"
          variant="outlined"
          id="Minimum-Income-filter"
          InputProps={{
            inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
          }}
        />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm glad that I helped you but please also don't forget to attribute the bounty it's not done automatically :)

Comment: @johannchopin sorry for the delay. I was on vacation, now it is done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you don't really need the `onValueChange` prop on the `NumberFormat` component since you already have an `onChange` on the `TextField` component that update the `minAssets` state.

So you can directly use this `minAssets` as the value of the prop `value` from `NumberFormat` like:

```js
return (
  <NumberFormat
    {...other}
    value={minAssets}
    getInputRef={inputRef}
    thousandSeparator
    isNumericString
    prefix="$"
  />
);
```

[image: Edit trusting-waterfall-3wvby]

Comment: Doesn't work. You are not updating any value, onChange is just not getting called.